# Alternativa a jQuery.fn.load

Tags: fetch

Al utilizar jQuery como se muestra en la línea de código siguiente, se carga "pagina.html" en el elemento indicado por contenedor:

```
$(contenedor).load('./pagina.html', function(response, status, xhr) {...});
```

Si como se muestra enseguida, el contenido de "pagina.html" incluye referencias a archivos CSS o JS, la página se [renderiza](http://bibliotecaprofesional.com/que-es-renderizar-una-pagina-web/) completamente antes de proceder a la incrustación en el contenedor:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css" />
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    ...
</body>
```

¿Existe alguna alternativa escrita en JavaScript puro (Vanilla) que cumpla con este propósito?

He probado la alternativa que incluyo enseguida, pero omite la ejecución de los posibles script JS referenciados por la página:

```
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", url, false);
request.send(null);

if (request.status == 200) {
    let elemento = document.getElementById(idElemento);
    elemento.innerHTML = request.responseText;
} else ...
```

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: el script al final del documento antes del cierre de `</body>` y haces un `window.onload = function() { //code o funcion a ejecutar al completar toda la carga del documento }` adicional puedes usar funciones `async` para esperar la respuesta!

Comment: Gracias @Bryro, tu sugerencia funciona perfecto si la carga se hace con jQuery.load pero no sí uso XMLHttpRequest o fetch.

Comment: eso no es jquery.... es javascript puro.